# Background image on mobile looks weird

Tags: html, css, mobile, mobile-website

When I'm inspecting the mobile version of my site, on a desktop and changing the width to a mobile device, the homepage image looks good, however, when I am on a real mobile device, the image looks weird, and too big.

How it looks on inspect:
[image]

How it looks on a real mobile device:[image]

Here is the code for the home page:

```css
#hero {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: url("../img/mobilebg.png") no-repeat center center fixed;
  -webkit-background-size: cover;
  -moz-background-size: cover;
  -o-background-size: cover;
  background-size: cover;
  -webkit-animation:linear infinite alternate;
  -webkit-animation-name: run;
  -webkit-animation-duration: 5s;
  z-index: 3;
}
```

```html
  <!-- ======= Hero Section ======= -->
  <section id="hero" class="d-flex flex-column justify-content-center">
    <div class="container" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-delay="100">
  </section><!-- End Hero -->
```

How could I fix this issue?
Appreciate any help,
Thanks

P.S: The site is helpsavetheseas.com

Comment: The Web page loaded in bot desktop and mobile are different.... In desktop its **https://helpsavetheseas.com** and in mobile its **https://helpsavetheseas.com/mobile.html**

Comment: Yes I know, I just added that in my question. That is not the issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to change the measuring unit of #hero height to px or em instead of vh
E.: delete the value `fixed` from the background property => `#hero{height:150em ;   background: url(../img/mobilebg.png) no-repeat center center;}`

Comment: Thank you! I think the main issue was the "fixed" background property